# set text attribue like (color, font, font size) not working in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to apply a specific format for navigation title

I write this code

```
// color
    UIColor *titlecolor = [self getUIColorObjectFromHexString:@"#5C8EB3" alpha:1.0];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:titlecolor}];

    // font face
    UIFont *font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"NotoKufiArabic-Regular" size:16.0f];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setTitleTextAttributes:
     @{NSFontAttributeName:font}];
```

there is no problem with color, the problem is with font
can anyone please tell me what is the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what you're seeing, only that the setting the font doesn't work. I'm going to make a guess that the font is the problem (it might not be). But to hazard a guess, try these to see if we can narrow the problem down a bit:

1. In your plist have you included the fonts under UIAppFonts aka Fonts provided by application?
2. Also, have you made sure that the correct targets are selected for your custom font?
3. Run this:

   `NSArray *familyNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[UIFont familyNames]];`
   `NSLog(@"Fonts: %@", [UIFont familyNames]);`

are your fonts listed?

4. Check the Font Book application on your mac, search for the font and find its correct name (called PostScript name). Use **exactly** this name to refer to the font.
5. Is the font included in the bundle resources? (Under Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.)
6. When you added the fonts to your project, did you select 'Copy items if needed'?
7. Are you doing this in a Launch Screens storyboard? They can't use custom fonts.

Comment: I am getting the following exception : when I add the font part, and when I remove font part it works 

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'

Comment: after use the code that list fonts, I found the name of font contain spaces in font list and when I use it as it is it works, Thanks

Comment: Also if you have multiple targets make sure you added the font to all targets

Comment: No problem, Amira. I always encouter problems with custom fonts. :)